# Comparing elements in a very large (100,000+ elements) ArrayList to every other element in the ArrayList

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, comparison, large-data

Currently I have a program going where I have to compare the elements of an ArrayList of maybe 150,000 or so custom objects to all the other elements in the ArrayList (excluding itself). It then needs to serialize the entire ArrayList (tested on an ArrayList of much fewer elements of the same custom objects). This works to about 22 Billion iterations, so clearly it's a very intensive process. It works, but maybe 2000 elements or so into the process, it begins to get much slower while memory usage and CPU usage have been steadily increasing the entire time.
What are some techniques that could perhaps make this process more efficient? Does not need to be fast necessarily (this program only needs to be ran once), just needs to get the job done without crashing or slowing down to the point where it's essentially useless. Any answers or points to the right direction would be very much appreciated =).

Comment: Increase the heap size. When the garbage collector starts running a lot, the performance is dropping even more.

Comment: 100k elements does not sound that much. From algorithmic point of view it would be enough just hashing each value and constantly adding them to a binary tree. Each collision would signify a duplicate. You can mark them or drop them or whatever you want. You could of course go for something more complex, like a balanced tree, but I don't think it is needed.

Comment: Is your comparison transitive?  If so, then this is just a sort.

Comment: Could you please post the relevant pieces of code? How do you do the comparison, how do you do the serialization, how your custom object class looks like (what interfaces are implemented, how do the implemented methods look like)?

Comment: Do you need to know if element occurs more than once, or do you need to sort them? What is your output?

Comment: Essentially it goes like this: 1)for every element in the list compare it to all the other elements in the list. 2) by "compare" I mean "run custom algorithm that takes the current element and the element being examined as input. If the value returned by that algorithm is above a certain number, add the index of that element to a list the element has that has all of the indexes it 'compares well with' and move onto the next element"

Comment: Hopefully that was not too vague. I just can't really post the code of the project I'm working on here

Comment: 150k^2 iterations comes to 22.5 billion iterations as you mentioned. Typically the ideal scenario here is to avoid quadratic complexity. However, we can't help with that if you don't describe exactly what you want to do (source code isn't necessary, just the high-level problem). Nevertheless, the immediate bottleneck here you're seeing is likely to be this part: `add the index of that element to a list the element has that has all of the indexes it 'compares well with' and move onto the next element`. If you are actually outputting entries for anything remotely close to the number...

Comment: ... of comparisons you are making, the amount of data gets explosive. If quadratic complexity is unavoidable here, you might be able to make the performance a bit more stable and reduce thrashing by transferring the list computed for each element to a disk output once you finish processing the 150k comparisons you make for a single element.

Comment: @Ike yes, this was what I was considering doing before I posted the question. Just wanted to see if there was a more straightforward method that I was missing. Thank you!

Comment: Probably this is the most straightforward way if we can't reduce the size of the data or the number of iterations. Even the OS can start to swap pages out behind your back in ways that have detrimental effects on performance at this kind of scale, and that isn't necessarily helped by having more DRAM. OS allocators are often optimized for smaller block sizes, and page allocation for large blocks can require slower branches of code in addition to the need to look for contiguous pages (which can cause out of memory errors to allocate a 10GB block even with 100GB free, e.g.).

Comment: Though a way to potentially help in this scenario other than just evicting stuff from memory yourself and transferring it to disk is to allocate smaller chunks of data (ex: arrays that don't get larger than 4 kilobytes). That yields *page-friendly* allocation, and with this kind of data scale, page-friendliness becomes just as important as cache-friendliness.

Comment: Using a BitSet to store the indices would lead to 150,000 * 150,000 bits, which, if you have enough memory (~3GB just for those bitsets), could still be manageable.

Comment: Yet another way that can help is to reduce the number of `new` calls you are making. Instead of allocating a boatload of N objects that just contain 3 float fields, e.g., allocate a single aggregate (ArrayList, e.g.) of N*3 floats. That avoids to allocate every single entry within the array list. That definitely helps from a paging/cache perspective -- not sure about GC, but I'd imagine it'd significantly help GC as well... or what `JB Nizet` mentioned -- if you can pack the data to a 150kx150k bit matrix, that wouldn't be so bad at all.

Comment: @Ike Sorry, I'm not familiar with the term "paging." Can you explain or link me to somewhere that explains what the term is?

Comment: @Shaken_Earth https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging. It's just a natural part of the process of moving memory from slower, bigger, cheaper memory hardware (disk at the extreme) to faster, smaller, expensive hardware (L1 cache line and then register being the two fastest). Computers move memory from bigger memory to smaller memory in chunks (ex: 8-byte chunks for 64-bit GP register, 64 byte chunks for the L1 cache, 4k or larger page chunks from secondary stage to DRAM for virtual memory, etc).

Comment: Typically if you want things to go fast, you want to play to the way these memory chunks are grabbed and transferred from slower memory to faster memory. Arrays do well there with sequential access because, for example, let's say you access element 1 -- the computer might grab a bunch of elements (2, 3, 4, 5, ...) and move their memory to faster memory. When you then access element 2, it's already in faster memory and so that goes very fast. However, when you get to very large data, memory allocators are often optimized to allocate for more modestly-sized memory chunks...

Comment: ... like within the kilobytes range along with the OS's virtual memory system. So if you go to megabytes or gigabytes and do a lot of allocations within that range, you can get bottlenecked by slower allocator branches (and possibly even face OOM errors due to a lack of contiguous pages available), and don't want to do this too often. So ideal sizes for memory blocks might be somewhere like the 4k range if you want to be both page-friendly and cache-friendly. Of course you can also allocate huge memory blocks -- that's also generally fine if you aren't doing it so often...

Comment: ... like the way `JB Nizet` suggested -- just allocate this 3 gigabyte bitset matrix all at once and use that. That's likely to be better than allocating 150,000 blocks each within the megabytes range. That also avoids the risk of thrashing if you just allocate all this memory in one go and avoid all kinds of subsequent allocations.

Comment: One thing though is that this strategy of preallocating 150kx150k elements (using a bitset, e.g., to compress each element down to a single bit) is useful if you need to say, access the data stored across rows in performance-critical loops. If you are just iterating through one element and doing 150k iterations of work and the results aren't needed in subsequent iterations, you no longer need to allocate so much data all in one go -- just allocate up to 150k elements (could still be a bitset if you wish, but booleans wouldn't be so large either), write results to disk and toss away the...

Comment: ... data structure. And then parallelize it if you want it to go faster but can't avoid the quadratic number of comparisons. There's no need to use up potentially anything close to 150k rows by 150k columns worth of elements in volatile memory if you only need to output each row to disk after computing it and can then toss it away.